# Another subject-verb agreement

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, verb-agreement

The verb 'need', always seems to throw me off somehow.

I feel in the sentence - "**For a person to be affected,  a copy of the gene from each parent need to be inherited**" - it should be "needs" in place of "need", because it written following the word "Each" (which is singular).

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Because 'a copy' is singular - that is what is being inherited.

Comment: The present "subjunctive" construction has been archaic since Patrick Henry used it. It's vertiginously high register in this quote, and could be viewed as a possible source of ambiguity. Don't do it.

Comment: @ Kate Bunting so you're agreeing that it should be "needs" instead ?